# How to add a gitignore folder to github actions?

Tags: django, git, github-actions

I have a Django Project and created a dev branch. In my .gitignore file I have the "media" folder. My project looks like this:

```
- Django Project/
    - app1/
    - app2/
    - media/
        - profile_pics/
        - default.jpg
    - .gitignore
```

In my gitignore I added `media`.

I've been trying to add github actions, so I created this ci.yml

```
name: Testing
on: push

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.6, 3.7, 3.8]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        python manage.py test
```

When I push the repo I received this message from Github Actions:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '****/media/default.jpg'
```

What is the best way to deal with this?

I could use git add media -f but I do not know if then this file would be in my repo and when I merge it with main and deploy it I would have that folder and overwrites the `media` in deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your media directory from `.gitignore` so that it is tracked by Git.  It sounds like you need that directory for your project to successfully build.

If you're concerned about large artifacts, then [see also `git lfs`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/configuring-git-large-file-storage) (large file storage) supported by GitHub.  Either way, you need to fix your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using media to store pictures of new users. I want to use Github actions to automate the deployment of my app after all tests pass. What would happen if I create a "feature" branch (and when ready I want to merge it and deploy the app) if someone in between has uploaded a new profile picture? Would this branch overwrite the media folder deleting the new profile pics or create other kind of conflict?

Comment: That sounds like something that is typically gitignored.  I would modify the app so that it references profile pictures in an alternate source  such as a CDN (like an Amazon S3 bucket for example).  And then your app will not require those to be files on a disk.   Your build will pass referencing remote images.  That would also require updating how pictures get uploaded so that they're put in a CDN on upload.